# why error function is invoked when form data is submitted to google forms?

Tags: ajax, forms

I am using jquery ajax to post my form data to google forms.  Every thing works fine but instead of done function fail function is invoked with ready state 4, status code 404, status text error.  My form data is inserted successfully. In nettabs it says 200 ok. Can anyone tell me why it invokes fail function?

Here's my code:

```
var params = {
"entry.870461494" : $('#name').val(),
"entry.1837540694":$('#email').val(),
"entry.794973559" : $('#cname').val(),
"entry.1682659266" : $('#cnumber').val(),
"entry.1004228063" : $('#city').val(),
"entry.874570127" : $('#interested_in').val(),
"entry.1619445424" : $('#bcategory').val().join()
}


$.ajax({
url : "https://docs.google.com/a/<company-name>/forms/d/<key>/formResponse",
data: params,
type : "POST",
dataType: "xml"
})  
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Saved to google docs: " + msg );
})
.fail(function( msg ) {
    alert( JSON.stringify(msg) );
});
```

Comment: Can you show your codes? and post the request & response

Comment: There's no reponse. Alert inside fail function says :  {"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"}